# VB.net Values of Custom Attributes

Tags: .net, getcustomattributes

I'm new to custom attributes, so I'm wondering if it is possible to get the values of the attributes. An example of the properties in my class which I use the custom attributes is:

```
Private mFiller As String
<Position(378), Length(34), DataType("A"), ParticipantDependant("P/D"), RequiredProperty("Required"), Format("Blank")> _
Public Property Filler() As String
   Get
      Return mFiller
   End Get
   Set(ByVal value As String)
      mFiller = value
   End Set
End Property
```

I'm trying to get the values of those attributes (ie. Get the Position = 378, Length = 34, etc.). The loop I was beginning with looks like this:

```
Dim gwlImport As New ClientGWLImport
Dim properties() As PropertyInfo = gwlImport.GetType.GetProperties
Dim tmpInfo As PropertyInfo
For Each tmpInfo In properties
   Debug.Print("Attributes for : " & tmpInfo.Name)
   For Each tmpAttribute As Object In tmpInfo.GetCustomAttributes(True)
      Debug.Print(tmpAttribute.ToString)
   Next tmpAttribute
Next tmpInfo
```

This gets me the names of all the attributes, but I'm not sure how to get the values. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Ryan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to know the type of the attribute.

For example:

```
Dim posAtt As PositionAttribute 
posAtt = CType(tmpInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(PositionAttribute), True)(0), PositionAttribute)
'Use some property of posAtt
```

By the way, you don't need to create a new `ClientGWLImport` to get its `Type` object.
Instead, you can write

```
Dim properties() As PropertyInfo = GetType(ClientGWLImport).GetProperties()
```

Comment: posAtt = tmpInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(PositionAttribute), True)(0) As PositionAttribute  ???? New syntax?

Comment: Other than the syntax error, it's exactly what I'm looking for. It should read: 
posAtt = CType(tmpInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(PositionAttribute), True)(0), PositionAttribute)

Comment: +1... I wonder why this got downvoted for a minor syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributedata.aspx) class exposes functionality for retrieving the complete definition of custom attributes decorating a type or member.

Comment: This should only be used on code that was loaded in a reflection-only context.  For normal code, you should use `GetCustomAttributes`, which will probably be faster and certainly be simpler.  See my answer.

Comment: @SLaks: Despite the fact that the CustomAttributeData class may have been originally designed to support something that would not otherwise have worked in a reflection-only context, it works just fine for a normally loaded assembly.  This is explicitly stated in the documentation: "CustomAttributeData can be used in the execution context as well as in the reflection-only context."

If the type of attribute is well-known, your approach would obviously be preferable.  However, I read the original posting as requesting a general-purpose approach to reading full attribute data.